# 「PHPエラーログ」と「php-fpmエラーログ」と「Nginxエラーログ」について

Tags: php, nginx

**PHPエラーログが、複数ファイルに分かれているのはなぜですか？**
・/var/log/php-fpm/
・/var/log/nginx/

---

**下記は「php-fpmエラーログ」ですか？**
・「PHPエラーログ」とは異なる？？

```
$ sudo less /var/log/php-fpm/error.log-20190428
[22-Apr-2019 04:08:06] NOTICE: error log file re-opened [23-Apr-2019
13:36:35] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase
pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children,
there are 0 idle, and 42 total children [23-Apr-2019 13:36:36]
WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase
pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children,
there are 0 idle, and 47 total children [23-Apr-2019 13:36:39]
WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (50),
consider raising it
```

---

**下記の方が普通のPHPエラーログだと思うのですが、**
・なぜ(PHPファイルではなく)nginxファイルに出力されるのですか？

```
$ sudo less /var/log/nginx/error.log-20190430
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: individual in
```

---

**環境**
・CentOS
・Nginx
・PHP7

Answer (score 0):

PHPは単独のスクリプトとして(コマンドラインから)実行することができ、この場合のエラー出力先は標準エラー出力や、自分自身がスクリプトの中で指定した任意のログファイル。

`/var/log/nginx/`に出力されるのはPHPをCGIとしてNginx経由で実行した場合 (厳密に言うとモジュール版などもあるみたいですが割愛)。

`/var/log/php-fpm/`に出力されるのはFPM (FastCGI Process Manager)、FastCGIという仕組みでPHPを実行する場合。